# SSRS subscription sends even though query fails

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, reporting-services

So I have a report that is sent out via an SSRS subscription to a group of emails. The report uses a stored procedure to obtain the data, however the report recently started to fail due to an arithmetic overflow error, this fix was simple enough to resolve however even though the stored procedure fails, the report is still sent via SSRS with only half of the data set (or the data up until the conversion error occurs)

This behavior is very undesirable, I am wondering if there is setting somewhere I can switch on that makes SSRS only send if the query was successfully run. It's worth noting the procedure takes about 5 minutes to run, yes I know it's too long and I know it needs optimizing however that is out of my remit unfortunately.

Even though the procedure eventually fails, it still returns a partial result set, but I wish for that not to be sent. Any ideas are much appreciated

Comment: If you have the Enterprise Edition of SQL Server you can use Data Driven Subscriptions in SSRS that would be able to be set up to only run when there's data in a SP. Or see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59637069/preventing-blank-ssrs-reports-from-emailing-without-enterprise-edition-no-data

Comment: Thanks. We do have enterprise however the problem is there is data in the procedure, even though it fails, it still returns a partial result set, up to the point where the proc fails. So I'm not sure this would work?